# Why isn't my port forwarding working when I've done everything, I think, correctly?

Tags: port-forwarding

I want to create a small web application that can be accessed by computers outside my local network (on the other side of the router). I've been trying to find a solution for several days now, and I've been browsing the questions and answers, but none of them help.

In order to do that, I decided to use the possibility of port forwarding. However, for some reason it doesn't work even though I think I have everything set up correctly. **What is strange is that port forwarding works when I access a given computer/application from another device within the given local network. The problem arises when I try to access from outside the local network.**

I am using `188.2.XX.XX:9999` (WAN IPv4 address bound to port 9999). There is no response (infinite waiting - `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`).

Things I've done so far:

1. I checked if my ISP uses CGNAT - considering the WAN address and the one I get with "whatismyipaddress" are the same, I'd say no
2. I checked via `ipconfig /all` what the MAC and local IP address of the computer on which the application is running are, and I set in the DHCP static lease that the MAC address of my computer has that static address (so that it does not change)
   [image]
3. I did port forwarding to port 9999 (I know some ISPs block port 80, so I tried with another port).
   [image]
4. I turned off the firewall.
   [image]

My simple web application (Golang):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the Home Page!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)

    port := 9999
    fmt.Printf("Server is running on http://192.168.0.11:%d\n", port)
    http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), nil)
}
```

What I am trying to do is access the application from outside the local network. I test it through my phone. Namely, if I am under WiFi (in local network), `188.2.XX.XX:9999` goes through as it should and I can access the application.

The problem is that when I go outside my local network (switch to mobile data) `188.2.XX.XX:9999` it just doesn't work. It waits for a while, and then I get a message that the request time has expired

Also, a friend from another part of the city (from another local network) tried to hit `188.2.XX.XX:9999`, it also doesn't work, the same situation as when I try with the phone.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What URL are you using to access your web application and what is the response you get when trying to access it?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am using 188.2.XX.XX:9999 (that's my WAN IPv4 address, I get the same when I go to `whatismyipaddress`). There is no response (infinite waiting - `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`).

Comment: Okay. If you have access to Curl (command line tool) try running this command: `curl -ILk 188.2.XX.XX:9999` and see if it gives any output. Next idea be to use nmap (command line tool) like this and see what the output is: `nmap -p 188.2.XX.XX`. And a most basic thing: Are you sure you are running your app on port 9999? What language is you app written in anyway?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Where do I call the curl command from, from what  device :)? I called from the computer where my web application is running and I got the following: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`  \n `Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2023 17:32:55 GMT` \n `Content-Length: 25` \n `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yes, I am running my application on port 9999. I can access it locally when I write 188.2.XX.XX:9999. I am trying from my phone to access it, and it works. Its Golang application.

Comment: So the curl command works in the same computer you are attempting to access it through web browser? If that is the case I would say this is an issue with the web browser. Clear the browser’s cache or try using another browser. “I am trying from my phone to access it, and it works.” So what is the problem? It sounds like everything is working.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yes, curl command work in the same computer I am attempting to access it through web browser. We did not understand each other, It also works when I am trying to access it within browser. But it is the same computer I am running web application, its all in local network. However, the problem is that it does not work  when someone outside my local network tries to hit 188.2.XX.XX:9999. For example if I switch to mobile data on my phone, then it is outside my local network and in that case when I try to access 188.2.XX.XX:9999, it does not work. I just wait endlessly.

Comment: The curl command should be used outside of your network. Same with the nmap command. They should be used to help you diagnose issues outside your network.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I just did it. I  downloaded API Tester on my phone, switched to mobile data (to be outside of local network) and ran the curl command you wrote. Simply endless waiting (After some time I get the message - `The request timed out`). If I go back to WIFI (back to local network) the curl command works and I get the answer I wrote above.

Comment: Well, then maybe your ISP is blocking ports. Try another one. Like 8080 or 8888 or even a low number like 88. I’ve helped as much as I can.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yes, I tried with different ports. Unfortunately, it doesn't work :( I tried now with 88. It works from the local, but not outside the local. :(

Comment: While I am not Networking Expert, I just comment that in your section for External IP put it as 0.0.0.0 (Some routers take this as any external IP) and in ports put 1 thru 65535.

Comment: @patkim I left all as it is and just put External IP to 0.0.0.0. It works now! Thanks!

Comment: @patkim What is strange is that when I set External IP to 0.0.0.0 it does NOT anymore case about Local IP (I swap it to 192.168.0.12 even thought the local IP of application executing web server is 192.168.0.11). Also it does not care about ports anymore (I set it all to 9999 and my web application is on port 88). In other words it is just important to write 188.2.XX.XX:88 (my external IP/port that application listen to) in web browser/curl and it is working no matter of what Internal IP and ports I set in router settings. Strange

Comment: @Cosmos Sounds like your router is screwy. Oh well!